# both $A$ and $B$ has eigenvalues other than $0,1$ and $rkA＋rkB＝n$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be diagonalizable $n$-dimensional square matrices. Suppose both $A$ and $B$ **has** eigenvalues other than $0, 1$, and and $rkA＋rkB＝n$. Show that such $A$ and $B$ do not exist.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
In my original problem,  $A＋B＝E$ is also condition, but I guess this condition is not needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "both $A$ and $B$ has eigenvalues other than 0,1". Are you saying that $A$ has at least one eigenvalue not equal to $0$ or $1$ (and the same for $B$)?

Comment: I assume that $E$ refers to the identity matrix, by the way. Note that this is notation is not common among English speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that $A + B = E$ is necessary. For instance, taking
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&0}
$$
gives us an example where both $A$ and $B$ have an eigenvalue not equal to $0$ or $1$ ($2$ for $A$ and $3$ for $B$), but the sum of the ranks is $1 + 1 = 2$.

On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ satisfy $A + B = E$, and $A$ is diagonalizable, then we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is diagonal so that
$$
A = \pmatrix{a_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && a_n}, \quad B = E - A = 
\pmatrix{1 - a_1 \\ & \ddots\\ && 1 - a_n}.
$$
The rank of a diagonal matrix is the number of non-zero values on its diagonal. We see that the sum of the ranks of $A,B$ must be at least $n$, and the sum can only be exactly $n$ if we have either $a_i = 0$ or $1 - a_i = 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$.

However, if $A$ has an eigenvalue not equal to $0$ or $1$, then there is an $i$ for which $a_i$ is neither $0$ nor $1$, which means that it is not true that $a_i = 0$ or $1 - a_i = 0$. So, the sum of the ranks is not $n$.

Comment: Could you explain me why WLOG we can say A and B are diagonal?

Comment: @bellow note that if $A = SDS^{-1}$ for a diagonal $D$, then $B = E - SDS^{-1} = S(E - D)S^{-1}$. In other words, the ranks of $A$ and $B$ remain the same if we replace $A$ with $D$.

Comment: Thank you! why rankA＋rankB is exactly n only if ai＝0 or 1-ai＝０？

Comment: Because he rank of a diagonal matrix is the number of non-zero values on its diagonal